# Currently available more than one custom data field?

Tags: surveymonkey

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/send_flow only seems to note one custom_id field, but the website displays up to six. Are these available to add data to or coming in the future? We are in need of one more field in our current integration. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have these additional custom fields stored in the address book (https://www.surveymonkey.com/addressbook/), then no, these fields are not available for the V2 API. Access to them will be available in the next version of the API. A date has not been set for its release, so I can only say that it's in the works.

If you are looking to have the additional custom fields piped into the email, then that is possible.

Example:

```js
{
  "survey_id": "########",
  "collector": {
      "type": "email",
      "name": "Test Collector",
      "send": true,
      "recipients": [
          {
              "email": "test@surveymonkey.com",
              "custom_id": "Custom Value 1",
              "recipient_attribute_values": ["Recipient Value 2", "Recipient Value 3"]
          }]
  },
  "email_message": {
      "reply_email": "test@surveymonkey.com",
      "body_text": "[SurveyLink] [RemoveLink] [FooterLink] [custom_1] [recipient_attribute_1] [recipient_attribute_2]"
  }
}
```